# Publish private Android app for external users using Google Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I have to publish an Android App (built using React Native) for my client. There is a requirement for the app to not be available for the general public so it can't be published as a public app. Users who sign up and get approved will be using the app. Majority of the users will not belong to my client's organization so Google Workspace private apps are not going to work in this scenario, since it is only for private apps for an organization's employees only.

There is the option of sending an APK but it requires users to allow installation of apps from unknown sources and that many users who might not be tech-savvy will probably find this difficult to do. The client wants it to be a smooth process, similar to any other app you install from the PlayStore.

Is there any solution where I can publish the app privately and send a link to the app to intended users? Ideally they should just open the link on their Android device and Google Playstore should open with my app selected and they can just press Install.

Thank you.

Comment: "Users who sign up and get approved will be using the app" - Where would they need to sign up? Why not directly in the app? So the app is published normally, but can be used only by those that have an approved account. Otherwise, if you just give them an apk or a link, what guarantee do you have that they would not share it with un-approved users?

Comment: Otherwise, what you describe is the [Close beta testing option of Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en#zippy=%2Cclosed-test-manage-testers-by-email-address-or-google-groups), but it's for a limited number of users, and they need to be added to a list before they get access to install the app.

Comment: @Adinia thanks for the comment. My client doesn't want the app to be searchable on Play Store, due to some internal reasons. We do understand that that APK can be shared with un-approved users, but they'll need valid credentials to go past the login screen. The reason we are looking for private publishing on Play Store is to allow smooth installs/updates, otherwise we'll have to share a new APK for any change in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out private publishing for external users is not yet available on either Google Play Store or Apple App Store. Private apps are only for employees, partners or contractors etc of an organization.

Had to make the app public on both platforms.